# Adding docker container to running OpenShift pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift-client-tools, openshift-origin

I can add a container to a pod by editing the pod template, but I'm looking for something simpler. Is there any way to add a container to a deployed OpenShift pod without editing the pod template? CLI preferable.

Comment: Great question ... creating/editing kubernetes configs are fragile to say the least so I too try to do everything by issuing CLI ... this should be a design priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command today that makes it easy to add a container to the pod template for an RC or deployment.  You can use oc new-app to quickly generate deployment configs that have multiple containers with

```
oc new-app php+apache+somethingelse
```

But this won't let you deeply customize those containers.

Agree this would be nice to have - as a mode to "run", perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add or remove containers in a running pod. If you are using replication controller, `kubectl rolling-update` is the easiest solution, but this will require editing the pod template. That said, are you sure you need to add your containers to the existing pod? Unless strictly necessary, it's better to just run the new containers in a separate pod, e.g. with `kubectl run <name> --image=<image>`

*Note: This is the generic kubernetes answer, there may be a more elegant solution for OpenShift*

Comment: FYI - See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4212 for a discussion of adding & removing containers in place.

Comment: On Openshift, you can add a new container by editing the deployment config. I'm fairly certain that OpenShift just restarts the pod, though.

Comment: +1 because: "OpenShift treats pods as largely immutable; changes cannot be made to a pod definition while it is running" source: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html